# Prevent the user from using the browser's backwards and forwards functionality using MVC 3, C# and unobtrusive-ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, browser, navigation, unobtrusive-ajax

*Problem*: Prevent the user from using the browser's backwards and forwards functionality.

*Using*: MVC 3 C# Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 .net framework 4.0 unobtrusive-ajax

I have a working MVC3 application using Html.BeginForm and friends in an ordinary out-of-the-book way with controller methods taking the different model objects as parameters and so on. Everything works fine except the user is able to hamper the expected functionality flow by using the browser's backward and forward navigation possibility. It is paramount that this should not be possible in this particular application.

I have "solved" the problem so far by using a home-made FSM (Finite State Machine) that intercepts tries to choose actions that are not compatible with the user's state by sending her back to the start of the application with the message that she cannot use browser navigation. This is really not very user friendly :-)

I am now trying to use unobtrusive-ajax to solve my problem (Ajax.BeginForm). Everything works fine until I try to bring the model data back and forth like when using Html.BeginForm. I have a lot of existing program code around the model and server side validation using the view/viewmodel/CustomValidation also, that I want to preserve in a possible Ajax solution variant.

This start-out scheleton works beautifully (details stripped off):

**CommandDispatcher.cshtml View:**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CommandDispatcher", "Adm", new AjaxOptions{ UpdateTargetId = "result" }))
{
    <div id="result">
        @Html.Partial("SomeAction001") @* Only run the first time *@
    </div>
}
```

**SomeAction001.cshtml partial view:**

```
<input type="submit" id="SomeAction001" name="SomeAction001" value="SomeAction001" />
```

**SomeAction002.cshtml partial view:**

```
<input type="submit" id="SomeAction002" name="SomeAction002" value="SomeAction002" />
```

**Controller:**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult StartCommandDispatcher()
{
    return View("CommandDispatcher");
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult CommandDispatcher()
{
    string action = translateToAction(Request);
    return findPartialView(action);
}

private static string translateToAction(HttpRequestBase request)
{
    string action = <find out which push button has been pressed and translate that to a known action>;
    return action;
}

private ActionResult findPartialView(string action)
{
    string partialViewName = <look up a dictionary or something>;
    ActionResult ar = PartialView(partialViewName);
    return ar;
}
```

To get this scenario working with data in it as well :-), I need to add model rendering and validation functionality.

Sending a model to the browser is no problem, exemplified by the following addition to a partial view: `@Html.Raw((model as MyViewModel).Field1)` which renders as hoped and expected. The problem I think is the direction from the browser to the controller.

How do I introduce such functionality?